# como restar una hora y sumar 8 minutos al timezone de Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

en config app.php en el Timezone tengo 'America/Asuncion' pero como este horario esta desfasado aqui en Paraguay le debo restar 1 hora y sumar 8 minutos lo que hice fue esto pero no surtio efecto

```
'mysql' => [
            'timezone'  => '-01:00', '+00:08'
        ],
```

Comment: ¿La idea es que todas las horas que utilices estén desfasadas 52 minutos hacia atrás?

Comment: si asi es pero ya probe hacer '-00:52' y no me toma :(

Comment: no se porque no funciona!!

Comment: @Shaz alguna otra forma?

Comment: oye Shaz al crearme la autenticacion de usuarios en laravel se me crea una vista que no me esta dejando modificarla es reset.blade.php porque pasa esto?